# Why my eraser go bad?

Tags: stationery

When utilizing my eraser on a specific book, it ceases to function effectively. After erasing a few words, a residue accumulates, impeding further erasure. Despite being a new eraser, it encounters difficulties exclusively with this particular book, while remaining functional on various other paper types. Maybe because the book is approximately five years old. Seeking a resolution to avoid the constant need for eraser scrubbing.

I would like to add that similar questions are asked previously but they all point towards eraser's fault but in my scenario the eraser is good but paper is real culprit.

Some important details:

- Book type: Printed
- Eraser: Normal ₹3 or 0.05$

May sound cheap but remember that economies differ greatly. GDP per capita of India is around $2500. Also this same eraser work on all other books. I have changed many erasers over this book but none of them work.

[image]

Comment: You can try different kind of eraser, e.g. something called "art gum eraser", which is more "gentle" and soft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An eraser is basically acting like a cloth, in normal instances the eraser will, due to friction have small bits come loose and they are rolled into small bits that collect the pencil and are then easily removed off the paper. (Insert blowing and hand wipe noise here :P )

If the paper in your book (what seems like a textbook) is smoother, then what could be happening is that the eraser has less friction thus the eraser is unable to wear down and discard the 'dirty' bits and it appears to be staying 'dirty'.

You can try one of three things.

1. Vary the pressure while erasing. Maybe less or more pressure on the eraser will yield a better result (be careful to not tear your paper).
2. Try a softer eraser, they require less friction to produce the bits that come off, you should be able to find a softer one at any stationary store or art supplier.
3. The last thing you can try is for this specific book as the paper is different, use a harder pencil this will deposit less graphite to the page and in theory the eraser will have more time to break up before it gets dirty.

Good luck.

Comment: Applying large pressure worked very well but I fear that paper might tear. Any tips for that?

Comment: Best bet in that case would be to try a softer eraser, however if you are set on using your current one then I suppose you could take the lid from an old ice cream container or an old credit card. Cut a notch about 1cm by 2cm (a rectangle just large enough), in the middle of the lid or card. Then place the plastic flat on the page and use your eraser through the window gap you cut. This will provided more stability to the paper than you can with only your free hands fingers. This isn't a guarantee and a softer eraser is still safer so if you attempt this try it on a page you don't mind tearing